# improving performance when you have many small input files using Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Currently I'm working with approximately 19 gigabytes of log data,

and they are much seperated so that the nubmer of input files is 145258(pig stat).

Between executing application and starting mapreduce job in web UI,

enormous time is wasted to get prepared(about 3hours?) and then the mapreduce job starts.

and also mapreduce job itself(through Pig script) is pretty slow, it takes about an hour.

mapreduce logic is not that complex, just like a group by operation.

I have 3 datanodes and 1 namenode, 1 secondary namenode.

How can I optimize configuration to improve mapreduce performance?

Comment: Did you enable `pig.splitCombination`? Did you use `PigStorage`?

Comment: 145258 is a lot of files, do you keep them all or remove after processing? If you keep them, than your biggest problem will be memory for the NameNode. Try concatenating them into a single big file and it will solve most of your problems.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, after all you guys suggest that I should combine files to bigger size ones. But the real problem is, there are hundreds of terabytes of data I have to process somehow stored in that way(many small files) and about 500gigabytes are newly stored every day. In this case, putting up into large files is another big problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set pig.maxCombinedSplitSize to a reasonable size and make sure that pig.splitCombination is set to its default true.

Where is your data? on HDFS? on S3? If the data is on S3, you should merge the data into larger files once and then execute your pig scripts on it, otherwise, it's going to take a long time anyway - S3 returns object lists with pagination and it takes a long time to fetch the list (also if you have more objects in the bucket and you're not searching for your files with a prefix only pattern, hadoop will list all of the objects (because there's no other option in S3).

Answer (score 1):

Try a `hadoop fs -ls /path/to/files | wc -l` and look at how long that takes to come back - you have two problems:

1. Discovering the files to process - the above ls will probably take a good number of minutes to complete. Each file then has to be queried for its block size to determine whether it can be split / processed by multiple mappers
2. Retaining all the information from the above is most probably going to push the JVM limits of your client, you'll probably see a huge amount of GC trying to assign, allocate and grow the collection used to store the split information for the at minimum 145k splits.

So as already suggested, try to combine your files into more sensible file sizes (somewhere near you block size, or a multiple thereof). Maybe you can combine all files for the same hour into a single concatenated file (or to day, depends on your processing use case).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is more of Hadoop than Pig. You might want to try to combine all the small files into a Hadoop Archive and see if it improves the performance. For details refer to [this link](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/hadoop-archive-file-compaction-hdfs-461.html)

Another approach you can try is run a separate Pig job which periodically UNIONs all the log files into one "big" log file. This should help in reducing the processing time for your main job.